# How to only display 4 most recently added database records?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I have run through the MVC3 Razor tutorial on ASP.Net, and and have started trying adapt it a bit to work with a small web project of my own.

What I have done so far is create a section that will add two fields to a new database record. A "News_Item" and a "News_Date" field.

Then when displaying this data on a separate page I only want to display the 4 most recently added records.

My View code (below) displays all entries in the database no problem, but I'd like to amend as stated above so it only displays the 4 most recent records. How would I go about doing this please? I am a beginner, and have no real prior experience with development.

In my Controller I have the following code for "Get":

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(db.News_Entries.ToList());
}
```

and just in case it is needed, here is the Model code:

```
namespace dale_harrison.Models
{
    public class News
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string News_Entry { get; set; }
        public DateTime News_Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewsDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<News> News_Entries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Comment: Thank you Abatishchev, unsure what you mean by that though - learning from the beginning here...

Comment: Harry, I mean do you use Entity Framework thus LINQ to Entities, or old LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your Actions code

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(db.News_Entries.OrderByDescending(n => n.News_Date).Take(4).ToList());
}
```

you should read [linq to entity tutorials](https://www.google.co.in/search?aq=1&oq=linq%20to%20entities%20&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=linq%20to%20entities%20tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

The following LINQ query:

```
var latest4 = db.News_Entries.OrderByDescending(n => n.News_Date).Take(4);
```

should be converted to the following SQL query:

```
select top 4 *
from news
order by date desc
```

Comment: Thanks again Abatishchev, I've not ever tried putting a SQL query into MVC, not sure how I should begin? Would you mind point me in the direction please?

Comment: @Harry: Glad this helped. Govind has posted more MVC-related answer so you've accepted his answer deservedly.